# Interrupt Long running Method of Seam Component

Tags: jboss, seam, interrupt, lifecycle

I do have a search Operation inside a method of a SEAM Component.
I found out, that I can terminate the execution using Lifecycle.endCall();
This Components is exported as a Webservice via Jax-WS. Sometimes, the client wants to
cancel the long running search process (e.g. starting a new one). HOw could i realize the possibility to stop the execution of the "fetchBooks" Method initiated by Client side?

```
@Name("bookSearch")
@AutoCreate
public class Booksearch{

   public List<Book> fetchBooks(String searchstring){
       ...........
         long running search
       ..........
   }
}
```

Thanking you very much in advance for helping me

Br,
Shane

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will start fetchBooks in new Thread and add to you service "stop" method, which interrupt fetchBooks thread